# Multidimensional arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I defined this multi dimensional array in C#:

```
int[,] values = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

Now the values are not longer in this form but in a Dictionary:

```
values2.Add("KeyA", new List<float> {1,4});
values2.Add("KeyB", new List<float> {2,5});
values2.Add("KeyC", new List<float> {3,6});
```

Now I'm trying to parse this dictionary in the two dimensional array again, but somehow there are problems:

```
List<float> outList = new List<float>();
values2.TryGetValue(values2.Keys.ElementAt(0) as string, out outList);

int[,] values = new int[outList.Count, values2.Keys.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < values2.Keys.Count; i++)
{
   List<float> list = new List<float>();
   values2.TryGetValue(values2.Keys.ElementAt(i), out list);

   for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
   {
       values[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(list.ElementAt(j));
   }
}
```

This throws an InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException. But why? I'm not able to convert the values properly.

Edit: I can be assumed that all the values in the dictionary have the same list length. I do check this somewhere else.

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException which line?

Comment: What is `metrics.Keys.Count` ? and in the declaration of `int [,] values` you are using the same variable in `values.Keys.Count`. That does not even compile?

Comment: values[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(list.ElementAt(j));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's as simple as getting *either* your lengths *or* your indexing the wrong way round. Here's your array creation:

```
int[,] values = new int[outList.Count, values.Keys.Count];
```

And you're then setting `values[i, j]` where `i` is less than `metrics.Keys.Count` and `j` is less than `list.Count`.

You could *either* switch the lengths round *or* set `values[j, i]` instead. Given the original statement of the array, I *suspect* you want the latter approach.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: Is there any LINQ method to do this?

Comment: @Pramodh: not that I'm aware of.